# Auto Layout not working properly

Tags: iphone, autolayout, scaling

I'm using Xcode 9.2. I'm normally debugging my app on my iPhone X but lately I tried to check if my animations scale properly on both simulated iPhone SE and a physical iPhone 6S. To my surprise many constraints were pretty messed up as though they were still scaled in relation to iPhone X's dimensions. When I switched the "View as:" option in Storyboard to respectively iPhone 8 and SE, everything layed out properly. But only when this option matched the device I was running the app on. Strange, I thought this is just for previewing and shouldn't have any impact on the actual app. Has anyone encountered it ?

Comment: How about some code examples and maybe some logs to clarify what you are asking, I bet it will make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the culprit...I was calling a method that was animating the layout too early - in viewDidLoad. I guess the views weren't properly placed and sized yet, that's why iOS used a default size which happens to be the last viewed device size in Storyboard.